# Spring null application context in JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Am trying to get the application context in my JSP page.
I have the following scriptlet in JSP.

```
       WebApplicationContext appCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(config.getServletContext()); 
       MyClass myClass = (MyClass)(appCtx.getBean("myClass"));
```

When using this a null pointer exception is getting thrown for the application context.
What am I doing wrong here?
I dont have a application-context.xml file because I dont need one. I have the usual dispatcher-servlet.xml with handler mappings.

Also, as an added info:
I am trying to access this "myClass" object which is being injected using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which reads from external environmental variables and injects to "myClass". Any pointers?

Update:

I tried using "RequestContextUtils" as suggested but now am getting "No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request" exception.
The JSP in which I am trying to access the bean is the entry point of the application . 
My view resolver looks like this,

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
        <value>myClass</value>
    </property>
   </bean>
```

The JSP am trying to access is outside of this "views" folder. Please advise

Comment: I don't do Spring MVC, but isn't just EL `${myClass}` possible in Spring MVC? Java code doesn't belong in JSP anyway.

Comment: Why are you trying to access the app context in the JSP? You're using MVC, anything for the view layer should be exposed through the controller.

Comment: @BalusC: Only if view resolver is configured to expose beans as attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext()` returns an application context associated with `ContextLoaderListener` (i.e. `applicationContext.xml`).

To get a context associated with `DispatcherServlet` you need to call `RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request)`.

Alternatively, you can configure [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) to expose beans as attributes. Then you can access beans in JSP as `${myClass}`. You can expose all beans by setting `exposeContextBeansAsAttributes` to `true` (I think it incurs some performance penalty), or explicitly list beans to be exposed with `exposedContextBeanNames`.

Comment: Have updated my question based on this suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work in my case

Comment: @Srini: If so, you won't be able to access `DispatcherServlet`'s context. It would be better to put all JSPs behind `DispatcherServlet`, just in case. It will solve your problem as well. To avoid writing trivial controllers you can use `<mvc:view-controller>`

Comment: As axtavt had suggested, moving the JSP so that it is behind the front controller did the trick. Thanks to everyone for their suggestion